# WebView - memory leaks in a simple code on devices <= 4.1

Tags: android, android-webview

my test code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myWebView;
    RelativeLayout WebViewLayout;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
        WebViewLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.webViews);
        myWebView = new WebView(this);
        WebViewLayout.addView(myWebView);
    }
}
```

causes memory leak in WebView on my 4.1 device (I use MAT for analysis):

```
Class Name
java.lang.Thread @ 0x4212f6b8 WebViewCoreThread Thread
'- <Java Local>, target android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread @ 0x4205d390
'- core android.webkit.WebViewCore @ 0x4212f608
'- mContext com.packagename.MyActivity
```

I have added onDestroy():

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    WebViewLayout.removeAllViews();
    if(myWebView != null) {
        myWebView.removeAllViews();
        myWebView.onPause();
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        myWebView.destroy();
        myWebView = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

But on 4.1 memory leak remains.
I tried to use getApplicationContext() instead [this], but result the same.

On 4.4 device no memory leaks.
Is it bug in WebView on <=4.1 ?
Is it possible to fix it?

Thanks!